# mysql #1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql, dynamic, triggers, procedure

I have been trying for a while now to dynamically store the fields and values of an changed table row into an API tableso I can transfer it between two applications.
The changes to each table are picked up by triggers that insert a row in an api table. This all works fine when I describe all the individual fields of each table that I want to trigger, but fails when I want to do it dynamically.
One of the stored procedures is:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN new_f_name varchar(40))
BEGIN
    SET @column_name_string_for_query = "";
    SET @parameter=new_f_name;
    SHOW COLUMNS FROM fa_fabric  WHERE @column_name_string_for_query := TRIM(", " FROM CONCAT("'", Field, "', ", Field, ", ", @column_name_string_for_query));

    SET @query_string = concat("INSERT INTO fa_api SELECT NULL,'fa_fabric' as a_table, 'PUT' as a_method, JSON_OBJECT('f_name','",@parameter,"') as a_keys, JSON_OBJECT(", @column_name_string_for_query, ") as a_data, NOW() as a_timestamp
        FROM fa_fabric
        WHERE f_name='",@parameter,"'");

    PREPARE statement FROM @query_string;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The associated triger for update is:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fa_fabric_update;
CREATE TRIGGER fa_fabric_update AFTER UPDATE ON fa_fabric
  FOR EACH ROW 
  CALL TEST(new.f_name);
```

The table fa_fabric (one of 20 tables) watched is:

- f_name  varchar(40) key
- f_supplier varchar(40)
- f_max_width int(11)
- f_hb_max_width varchar(20)
- f_cut_method varchar(10)

The api table fa_api is:

- a_id int(11) auto_increment
- a_table varchar(20)
- a_method varchar(11)
- a_keys varchar(100)
- a_data longtext
- a_timestamp datetime

Executing the stored procedure by itself works fine, calling it from the trigger though gives the error: #1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
I would really appreciate some help.